# What's uniform distribution defined on half-open interval?

Tags: uniform-distribution

For some reason I'm finding an uniform distribution asked to be defined as a half-open interval $[0, 2)$. Either I did something wrong in doing the set calculation or then this is a form of uniform distribution.

Is it an uniform distribution? What properties does it have?

Comment: It is the same distribution as the uniform distribution on the closed interval, the events aren't called the same name (an interval can't end in "$\ldots 2]$" in your case), but the probabilities are the same: $P((a,b))=\frac12 (b-a)$ for all $a,b$.

Comment: If the question is : "can I define a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,2)$", then the answer is yes, because it results from a scaling, by half, of the Lebesgue measure. What I do not understand is : "I'm finding a distribution ..." . Do you mean that you were calculating a certain distribution function, and came upon this distribution?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I'm given that a set where I plug some continuously varying variables that define the "domain" of the uniform distribution. And I got out $[0,2)$ in one case.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier But what's $b$?

Comment: @mavavilj I sincerely hope I am not asking for too much, but I request you to , if possible, insert this question into the above post as well. We will deal with both simultaneously.

Comment: @mavavilj $b$ is any element of $(a,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

An *uniform continuous distribution* is one where the *probability denisity function* over the support interval is unbiased (ie constant).

Generally, for any $a<b$, if $X\sim \mathcal U[a;b)$ ($X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $[a;b)$), then the pdf is $f_X(x) = \tfrac 1{b-a}\mathbf 1_{x\in[a;b)}$ and the CDF is $F_X(x)= \tfrac{x-a}{b-a}\mathbf 1_{x\in[a;b)}+\mathbf 1_{x\in[b;\infty)}$

Specifically: $X\sim \mathcal U[0;2)$ then $f_X(x) = \tfrac 12\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;2)}$ and $F_X(x)= \tfrac{x}{2}\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;2)}+\mathbf 1_{x\in[2;\infty)}$

---

PS: Also, an *uniform discrete distribution* is one where the *probability mass function* over the support interval is unbiased.

---

NB: $\mathbf 1_{x\in[a;b)}=\begin{cases} 1&:& a\leqslant x< b\\ 0 &:& \text{else}\end{cases}$